# Start wildfly with jar file for demo

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, demo

I want to be able via command line to start wildfly and then, deploy my war archive. Similar behaviour I could reach with having arquillian test + mvn wildfly plugins. I could start test, annotated with @Arquillian via mvn, wildly will be downloaded to a target folder via mvn plugin, in test I create war, and run test methods.

Something similar is needed, but without tests.
I want to run via mvn my application for demo, application server also should be started, so I could show how it works via browser, and only then, manually I could shutdown the application server.

The previous option is supposed that I give my source code and the whole project to someone, who can start it. It is not always a good choice. Sometimes, I just want to send a self executable jar file, that already includes some light version of wildfly (if it is possible). So I could starts server with deployed my code to show how it works. It will allow me to hide sources. How can I create such archives?

Perhaps there are some other options/tools. Using wildfly is a preferrable, not not a "must have" option.

Any advices?

Comment: what is this demo jar? what kind of deployment?

Comment: maybe wildfly swarn could help?